# How to Install Symbian in qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, symbian, nokia

I installed qt libraries from ubuntu software centr and and installed qt creator from .bin file

Now it supports apps for pc only. I want to add support for symbian, how can I do it?

I can't find a specific library for symbian.

Comment: However, why you need to develop software for Symbian anymore? Even Nokia has stopped development ans support of Symbian OS!

Comment: But i wanna create apps for existing mobiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mobile development support, you should have Qt Mobility installed on your computer, its name must be like qtmobility or sth in Software Center.

You also can directly install Qt Creator which will include both libraries necessary for Symbian and emulators, plus it s a nice IDE, it's in Software Center, unless i'm wrong.

Comment: But i already installed qtcreator
(in bin format not deb)
then how to install this specific library without downloading entire qt sdk